WPF ComboBox Display list of selected values
I have a ComboBox on my form, the logic of which differs from the usual one. It contains check boxes. When checking checkboxes, a list of checked values ​​is displayed in ComboBox.Text. This happens in the event handler. To avoid the user selecting an object (namely, selecting an element, not selecting a checkbox), in the ComboBox.SelectionChanged handler I set the selected object to null. But at the same time, the ComboBox stops displaying the list of values ​​and shows an empty line.
What can be done so that when you select an element in a ComboBox, the list of values ​​does not disappear?
Here XAML (btw ComboBox is located in StackPanel):
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}" SelectionChanged="OnCbObjectsSelectionChanged" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Checked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

Here code-behind for event handlers:
private void OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)sender;
    var comboBox = (System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox)checkBox.Tag;
    ChangeComboBoxDisplayText(comboBox);
}

private void OnCbObjectsSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBox = (System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox)sender;
    comboBox.SelectedItem = null;
    ChangeComboBoxDisplayText(comboBox);
}

private void ChangeComboBoxDisplayText(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBox)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var selectedItems = comboBox.Items.OfType<StyleInfoItem>().Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
    string displayText = string.Join(", ", selectedItems.Select(x => x.Name));
    comboBox.Text = displayText;
}


MVVM approach:
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public void RisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new(propertyName));
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public class Item : BaseViewModel
    {
        public static event EventHandler? IsCheckedChanged;

        public required string Name { get; init; }

        bool isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get => isChecked;
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                RisePropertyChanged();
                IsCheckedChanged?.Invoke(this, new());
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = [
        new() { Name = "1", IsChecked = true },
        new() { Name = "22" },
        new() { Name = "333" },
    ];

    public string CheckedItems => string.Join("; ", Items.Where(o => o.IsChecked).Select(o => o.Name));

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Item.IsCheckedChanged += (s, e) => RisePropertyChanged(nameof(CheckedItems));
    }
}

XAML:
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          Text="{Binding CheckedItems, Mode=OneWay}"
          IsEditable="True"
          IsReadOnly="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

I used a quick trick with static event to monitor for changes from parent class, otherwise it should be pretty straightforward what is going on.
Demo:


When clicking ComboBoxItem rather than its CheckBox, then its value will be selected and displayed. Same undesired effect occurs when using arrow keys. The possible workaround is to force Text notification after each such change of selected item.
Add binding to selected item:
<ComboBox ... SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ... />

Add property to view model and rise notification from setter:
public Item SelectedItem
{
    get => default!;
    set => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => RisePropertyChanged(nameof(CheckedItems)));
}


This is a good solution, but it doesn't solve my problem. Displaying a list of selected values ​​in a ComboBox works in my version, but I need this list not to disappear when a value is selected.

@IvanSerdukov, didn't noticed that issues. Try the fix.

I suggest you to cancel the bubbling of the click (MouseLeftButtonDown) event on the element and handle the CheckBox select events
    public static class HandlerHelper
    {
        public static RoutedEventHandler HandledTrue { get; } = (s,e) => e.Handled = true;
    }

    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                  MouseLeftButtonDown="{x:Static local:HandlerHelper.HandledTrue}"
                  Checked="OnChecked"
                  Unchecked="OnUnchecked"/>
    </DataTemplate>


Thank you, maybe I don’t understand something, but how can I prevent clicking on a ComboBoxItem from being triggered, while still allowing clicking on the checkbox?

@IvanSerdukov
This is not a ban, but a cancellation of the Routed event bubbling. Or rather, marking the event as "handled" e.Handled = true. Such events are not processed by default in further movement along the visual tree, as if they no longer exist. In this case, MouseLeftButtonDown will be processed at the CheckBox level, but this event will not bubbling up from it. Accordingly, ComboBoxItem will not receive this event (more correctly, it will pass through itself without processing).

@IvanSerdukov
I admit honestly - I haven't tested it.
I have doubts about the necessity of such complexities, since CheckBox is a button and MouseLeftButtonDown is already cancelled in it and Click is raised instead. Perhaps I didn't quite understand the problem correctly and am offering a solution that is not needed.
